# How fix Error message bot Telegram with JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram, telegram-bot

How can I fix this error in JS?

> error_code: 403,
> description: 'Forbidden: bot was blocked by the user'

This initial code

```js
bot.start( (ctx) => {
    console.log(ctx.chat.id)
    if (newClient(ctx.message.chat.id)) {
        createLog(ctx.message.chat.id)
        ctx.reply("Message")
    } else {
        ctx.reply("Message")
    }
})
```

Comment: Unblock the bot?

Comment: I have this error 

https://pastebin.com/wVMcS5xY

Answer (score 1):

The error message obviously says what happened; The bot was blocked by the user.

To fix that, you have to add a condition that checks if the user blocked the bot. Or the user should unblock the bot.